# IE 10 and Edge take 20+ seconds just to send request

Tags: rest, internet-explorer, post, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

I've got one `POST` request that is taking close to 30s from start to finish on IE/Edge only. Here are the timings:

[image: IE Network Tab Timings]

When would the sending take this long? I'm only sending an object with one property (10-character string). In both Chrome and FireFox it does not delay for over 25+ seconds.

Comment: What connection settings may be different between your browsers? Are you on a domain using a proxy? FX and chrome don't use Security zones. If you are using a localhost website for development/testing use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone it maps to.. If you use Fiddler it will use its built in proxy, bypassing IE's settings.

Comment: I am not using any proxies, but another developer is using Fiddler and experiences the same delay.